# Duplicate records while insertion into grid asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a page which consists of a grid and add new button. When the user clicks add new button he gets several fields to be entered. So, when he clicks submit I usually write a query which checks if there is an entry already in the database. In this case, I succeeded. However, my task is to also show the records identical and let the user decide to proceed or not.

SO, I am not sure of how to proceed with this one. So, can anyone just help me in giving an idea on how to proceed with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a checkbox to allow the user to indicate whether they want to allow duplicate entries or not.  Your backend code would then read the state of that checkbox and ignore the duplicates accordingly.

Another option might be to return an error message that includes the LinkButton.  This LinkButton could fire off an alternate Add method that would ignore duplicates.